# Why $x(t) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{3}t)$ and $y(t) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{3}t)$ are considered identical signals?

Tags: continuous-signals

Consider the following question that I toke from [*Signals and systems: Part I*](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/assignments/) exercises, question 1:

> (b) With $x(t) = \cos(\omega_x(t + \tau_x) + \theta_x)$ and
>   $y(t) = sin(\omega_y(t + \tau_y)+ \theta_y)$, determine for which of the
>   following combinations $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are identically equal for all
>   $t$.

Given that:
$$
\begin{matrix}
\omega_x & \tau_x & \theta_x & \omega_y & \tau_y & \theta_y \\
\hline
\pi/3    & 0      & 2\pi     & \pi/3    & 1      & -\pi/3 
\end{matrix}
$$

The [solutions manual](http://ocw.mit.edu/resources/res-6-007-signals-and-systems-spring-2011/assignments/MITRES_6_007S11_hw02_sol.pdf) shows that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are identical with these values:

> $\omega_x = \omega_y$, $\omega_x\tau_x + \theta_x = 2\pi$, $\omega_y\tau_y + \theta_y = \frac{\pi}{3}(1) - \frac{\pi}{3} = 0 + 2\pi k$
>
> Thus, $x(t) = y(t)$ for all $t$.

It toke me sometime to understand this, but still I'm not sure how these signals are identical.

If we substitute the constants we will get:

$$
\begin{align*}
x(t) &= \cos(\frac{\pi}{3}(t + 0) + 2\pi) \\
     &= \cos(\frac{\pi}{3} t + 2\pi) \\
     &= \cos(\frac{\pi}{3}t) \\
\\
y(t) &= \sin(\frac{\pi}{3}(t + 1) - \frac{\pi}{3}) \\
     &= \sin(\frac{\pi}{3}t + \frac{\pi}{3} - \frac{\pi}{3}) \\
     &= \sin(\frac{\pi}{3}t)
\end{align*}
$$

which is clear that $x(t) = \cos(\frac{\pi}{3}t)$ and $y(t) = \sin(\frac{\pi}{3}t)$ are not identical:

[image: plot x(t) = cos((pi/3) * t, y(t) = sin((pi/3) * t]

Can someone please explain what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is obviously an error in the problem formulation. From the given solution, the problem should read

> With $x(t) = \cos(\omega_x(t + \tau_x) + \theta_x)$ and
>   $y(t) = \cos(\omega_y(t + \tau_y)+ \theta_y)$, determine for which of the
>   following combinations $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are identically equal for all
>   $t$.

In this case the given solution $\omega_x=\omega_y$ and $\omega_x\tau_x+\theta_x=\omega_y\tau_y+\theta_y+2\pi k$ makes sense. The solution to the problem as it is given (with $y(t)=\sin(\omega_y(t + \tau_y)+ \theta_y)$), would be

$$\omega_x\tau_x+\theta_x=\omega_y\tau_y+\theta_y-\frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi k$$

Comment: Yeah, if you look at the solutions manual it simplifies a different equation to the one in the question.